# Undertow (I think) closes connection after SSL Client Hello

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, undertow

I'm trying to setup my springboot app on Debian Stretch production server. App uses TLS 1.2 and HTTP2 so I ran it with embedded Undertow and it worked flawlessly on Windows, however it seems to just drop connection after Client Hello on Linux.
this is what it looks like in wireshark:

[image]

I was able to connect over insecure http/1.1 with no problems though. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with TLS, because turning it off in application.properties allows Undertow to fallback to http/1.1. (I need multiplexing though)

And I can't find anything that could cause such behaviour. It's not keystore because I get no errors in Java.

The only thing I had to change from Windows were JVM parameters I had to change to make it use IPv4:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:/home/dptools/alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses -jar dpTools-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Where was the packet capture taken? I assume at the client side. Please do a parallel packet capture at the server side to verify that the FIN is actually caused by the server and not by some deep packet inspection middlebox (like a firewall) in between.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It was indeed taken on client side, but tcpdump on serverside also captures it. https://puu.sh/xUshC/77b51ab95e.png

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was keystore after all, not exactly keystore, but keypair inside. Apparently putting special characters in alias is not a good idea. after switching to alphanumeric alias it works. What concerns me is lack of any error on socket binding.